# How can use Table for two functions obtained from NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, list-manipulation

I have obtained a numerical solution using NDSolve for two functions a(x) and b(x). how do I use Table to make a list of a(x) vs b(x) values. is it simply
Table[{a(x),b(x)},{x,0,100}] or should I use something else since a(x) and b(x) are not analytic?
the following is part of my code(a(x) and b(x) is f(z) and phi(z)):

```
sol = NDSolve[{-((
   f[z] ϵ[
     z] (2 - 2 ϵ[z] + (1 + z) Derivative[1][ϕ][
        z]))/(1 + z)^2) + 
  Derivative[1][f][
    z] ((-12 + 12 ϵ[z]^2 + 
       4 (1 + z) Derivative[1][ϵ][z] - 
       4 Derivative[1][ϕ][z] - 
       4 z Derivative[1][ϕ][z] - 
       6 (1 + z) ϵ[z] Derivative[1][ϕ][z] + 
       Derivative[1][ϕ][z]^2 + 
       2 z Derivative[1][ϕ][z]^2 + 
       z^2 Derivative[1][ϕ][z]^2)/(2 (1 + z) (2 - 
         2 ϵ[z] + (1 + z) Derivative[1][ϕ][z]))) + (
   f^′′)[z] == (
  c^2 (3 (1 + z) ϕ'[z] + 6 (1 - ϵ[z])))/(1 + z)*
  H[z]^2*D[(8*Pi*G* ρ[z])/(3*Subscript[a, 0]^2*(H[z])^2), 
   z], (1 + z)^2*ϕ''[
    z] - (2 - ϵ[z])*(1 + z) ϕ'[z] == 
 6 (1 - ϵ[z]), ϕ[zi] == 0, ϕ'[zi] == 0, 
f[zi] == (5 c^2)/Subscript[a, 0]^2 H0^2 (1 + zi), 
f'[zi] == 0}, {f[z], ϕ[z], ϕ'[z]}, {z, 0, zi}];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{ϕ'[z], f[z]} /. sol], {z, 0, 10000}]
```

Comment: What happens when you use Table[{a(x),b(x)},{x,0,100}] ?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal working example of you `NDSolve` code? It doesn't need to include all the bells and whistle of your actual code, but it is necessary in order to see how you are storing the functions `a` and `b`, *especially* since you are using syntax that doesn't work in *Mathematica* (functions are defined using square brackets, not parentheses).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You have two ODEs and five unknown functions, so `NDSolve` cannot provide an answer.  You also have undefined constants.  Finally, ` (
   f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[z]` should be `f''[z]`.

Comment: Fix the mentioned problems and then Table[{f[z], φ[z]} /. sol[[1]], {z, 0, 100}]

Comment: I have all the functions and constants defined but I didn't put them here. and I don't know why its f[prime][prime] here. I just copied the code with f'' but here it appears like this.

Answer (score 1):

I Have finally found what was causing the problem. it was with notation. I define my constant a_o but in the equation I have used a_0. Once I changed that it was working.